# Performance hit if I use many YUI DataTable controls in a page

Tags: asp.net, javascript, yui-datatable

I am planning to use YUI DataTables (for look-up) extensively in my web application. I may give option to open approximately 15 DataTables in a page. I am taking care of caching the content. I would like to know if there would any performance hit on the application. Any inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with YUI tables that much, but I have worked with other libraries and plug-ins.

The major performance hit for most libraries is really how much data do you have in those tables. Larger tables tend to have larger render times. Adding a bunch of them together and you may find long waits to get to the data.